# Can an App Service connect to a Network Drive?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-appservice

Can an App Service living in an App Service Environment/VNet that has an Azure Gateway to an on prem network work with network files? I'd like to be able to read and save files on a network drive but given that this will take some trial and error want to make sure it's a viable option first.

The backup plan is to use Azure File Sync to Azure Storage but given the delay in cloud files syncing, it may not work for my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure App Services does not support SMB.

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#restricted-outgoing-ports

> Regardless of address, applications cannot connect to anywhere using
> ports 445, 137, 138, and 139. In other words, even if connecting to a
> non-private IP address or the address of a virtual network,
> connections to ports 445, 137, 138, and 139 are not permitted.

Comment: This is true only for apps running directly on Windows plans. If you run your app using Docker container on App Service, sandbox limitations are not applied as Docker container is your sandbox then. You definitely can use 445 port from container running on App Service.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this with SMB based fileshare hosted on-prem on a windows server from "logic apps" in azure.  I have used the built in "file share"-actions backed by azure data gateway.
I realize that this is different technology however;  There should be absolutely nothing stopping you for doing this for app services ( running some SMB-client for C#) as long as you have connectivity as far as I can understand

Comment: thanks. what is file share actions? is that a specific azure product? or were you just connection to a network drive using \\servername\filename

Comment: Yes, it is a spesfic product : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-using-file-connector. "Actions" are small programs and the logic app uses the app service "behind the scene". I used it as an example because it supports your plan of writing custom code and running it in  a app service.

Comment: App Service has 445/TCP blocked from the sandbox so none of this is possible. What you could do is use Azure Files and programmatically transfer files to/from it via its APIs in your App Service Web App, then mount the Azure Files instance as SMB on-prem or wherever you need may need it.

Comment: @evilSnobu App Service has 445/TCP blocked only from its sandbox which is used when you host apps as code on Windows. If you host app on Linux plan or use container on Windows, 445 is not blocked at all. You still cannot mount SMB share via mount command as it needs SYS_ADMIN capability but you can run any SMB client from your container and it will work.